# Why are values of Python objects or PyTorch layer objects in my code not changed?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

This may be a naive question but I'm confused now.
Assuming I have the following `torch.nn.Embedding` layer with the following vector values:

```
t_emb = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [3,3,3]])
display(t_emb)

tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]])

emb = torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(embeddings=t_emb)
emb.weight

Parameter containing:
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]])
```

Now if I get the 0<sup>th</sup> vector in the embedding layer and add another vector to itself, I get an updated vector instead of the original 0<sup>th</sup> vector in the embedding:

```
t1 = emb(torch.tensor(0))
t2 = torch.tensor([3,3,3])
t1 += t2
t1

tensor([4, 5, 6])
```

But why the values in the embedding layer did not update like `t1`?

```
emb.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: Because there is nothing in this code updating the embedding weights? I think you completely misunderstood how variables work here.